# Angularjs $routeParams me da undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector

La verdad he hecho esto cientos de veces y me resulta, capaz es una tontería que no estoy viendo.

Mi problema es que cuando hago un `$location.path('/Miruta/'+id);` (La url se me genera de esta forma `http://localhost/mysite/WebContent/#/alta/minDetalle/2789`) cuando llega a la url destino, el `$routeParams.id` me viene como undefined, y debería ser `2789` dejo el código.

```
//Parte del App.js
app
  .config([
    '$routeProvider',
    '$locationProvider',
    '$httpProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

      $httpProvider.interceptors.push('sacgHttpInterceptor');

      $routeProvider

      .when("/alta/minDetalle/:id", {
        templateUrl: "pages/altas/mindetalle.html",
        controller: 'MinDetalleCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      })
      .otherwise({
          templateUrl: "pages/home.html",
          controller: "homeCtrl"
        });
}]);


//Registro.js
//Llamo mi servicio de guardar

  ObjectFactory.save(min).then(function(data){
    console.log('Salvado!!!');
    var id = data.idMinutario;
    resetDropDown();
    $location.path('/alta/minDetalle/'+id);
  });

//Js donde redirecciono.
(function(){
  'use strict';

  /*
   * Para mejor lectura del codigo es mejor colocarlo de esta forma (Nombre
   * cotrolador, Nombre de funcion)
   */
  app.controller('MinDetalleCtrl', MinDetalle);

      //  /* Inyecto las dependencia que va a necesitar mi funcion main */
 MinutarioDetalle.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', 'ObjectFactory', "$location", 'DTOptionsBuilder', '$filter', '$q', "ObjectFactoryPersistence", "$interval", '$routeParams'];

  ////Funcion de mi controller
  function MinutarioDetalle($rootScope, $http, ObjectFactory, $location, DTOptionsBuilder, $filter, $q, ObjectFactoryPersistence, $interval, $routeParams){

    ///Asignamos this to vm (ViewModel) Porque amamos los VM :D

  console.log("llegue bien");
  console.log($routeParams.id); //undefined

    var vm = this;
    vm.hideToggle = true;
    vm.hideToggleDocumentos = true;
    vm.hideToggleAnexos = true;


    vm.testCode = "Hellos World";

    vm.click = clickme;

    function clickme(){
      alert('test');
    }
  }

})();
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal, creo que es algo del `VM` que estoy tratando de implementar, pero honestamente no se donde esta el error.

Adicionalmente, no veo ningún error en la consola.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tienes la misma cantidad de elementos en el `$inject` que en la función del controlador. Así, los inyectados quedan todos mal asignados, corridos por así decirlo; Pues angular no mira el nombre de los parámetros (cuando usas `$inject`) sino su orden.

Osea, que lo que haces cuando haces `console.log($routeParams.idMinutario);` es en realidad `console.log($interval.idMinutario);`.. lo que seguramente esta indefinido.

Fíjate...

```
MinutarioDetalle.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', 
              'ObjectFactory', "$location", 'DTOptionsBuilder', 
              '$filter', '$q', "ObjectFactoryPersistence", 
              "$interval", '$routeParams']; // 11 parametros

////Funcion de mi controller
function MinutarioDetalle($rootScope, $http, ObjectFactory, 
              $location, DTOptionsBuilder, $filter, 
              $q, ObjectFactoryPersistence, $interval, 
              $routeParams){ // 10 parametros
```

#### Solución:

Debes atregar `$scope` como primer parámetro de `MinutarioDetalle`, o eliminarlo del `$inject`. Ya que no lo usas, elimínalo.

Saludos.

Comment: La verdad muchas Gracias, me funciono, no me había dado cuenta de este detalle.

Answer (score 1):

Además, en la ruta defines el parámetro como `id` pero luego recoges del `$routeParams` un parámetro llamado `idMinutario`.

Comment: Hola Fue un Typo al momento de escribir, ya que por motivos de seguridad de la empresa debía cambiar muchos nombres antes de publicar la pregunta. Gracias de igual forma.